# Best and simple way to prevent automatic backups filling all disk space in Linux, before it actually happens

Tags: perl, disk-space-utilization, shell-scripting, quota, sysadmin

Which do you think is the best and most simple way to prevent automatic backups filling all disk space in Linux, before it actually happens?

I would like to automatically recycle the oldest ones when the disk reaches, let's say 85% full

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What are you doing, what are you expected to get, what you've got instead?

Comment: Look at sizes of previous backups, compare them with `df` output.

Comment: Remember to have a good monitoring system that will alert you before your disk fills up.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `rsnapshot` with appropriate retention policies. It has the (big) added advantage to provide an incremental backup approach (ie: almost no additional space is used by two identical backups) while giving you always up-to-date "full tree" in the latest snapshot (ie: what other products call "syntetic full backup").

However, this approach **must** be combined with robust free space monitor/alarm, should used space increase faster then expected (for example via unique data, which are not shareable between incremental runs).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separated storage for backup, may be a network storage or a disk partition. That will keep your system safe from your backup job.

I agree with @shodanshok monitoring your system with a tool is another key. have a look to netdata !